# Fadein stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I was updating some html and for some unconnected reason the fadein for the [logo before the footer](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2014/June/4/neighbourhood-watch.html#) stooped working - the logo should fade in when it's at the end of the page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #townEnd first
    $("#townEnd").hide();

    // fade in #townEnd
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() -300) {
                $('#townEnd').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#townEnd').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#townEnd a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({a
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

html:

```
  <div id="townEnd">
    <a href="#">Inside<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%></a>
  </div>
```

It's getting an uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier
Ideas appreciated

Comment: I've recreated the example above directly using Chrome DevTools and the fade in (and out) are working for me. What's working incorrectly?

Comment: Well, the syntax error is quite obvious. The error message should even tell you *where* it is!

Comment: It should display a line number

Comment: @uname12 You could if you looked closely at those few lines?

Comment: You've got a stray character in the animate function object. This line:  `$('body,html').animate({a` <-- that `a` obviously doesn't belong. What Bergi means is that the error message should indicate roughly what line the error is occurring. Since you're learning, before you fix this, take a look at the line number in the error and compare to the line number where the stray character is, and you'll see they should be the same. Learning how the error messages work will help make sure you spot errors like this very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

you have a floating `a`. this should work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #townEnd first
    $("#townEnd").hide();

    // fade in #townEnd
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() -300) {
                $('#townEnd').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#townEnd').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#townEnd a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
</script>
```